# Where I can get Tor Browser Bundle source?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, source-code

There is [source](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) of Tor daemon, but I can't find source of Tor Browser:

https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#linux

Where is the open-source?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en
Last expand menu -> source code

https://www.torproject.org/dist/tor-0.2.4.20.tar.gz

and TorBundle

https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser-details.html.en#build

Comment: This is not the same, bundle is modified Firefox, you try to point on source of daemon.

Comment: @ConcealmEnt the third link in the answer contains a link to the current Tor Browser Bundle Source code, which includes instructions on how to build it.

Comment: @Samuel Walker, it is dead link. There is no `src`: https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/

Answer (score 1):

Well, the direct link to the source package does not work for me either, at least not right now.
But you could try following the [build instructions](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/build-scripts/INSTALL) that are found on the [source code page](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser-details.html.en#build) that krang mentioned (thus obtaining the latest version directly from the repository).
**And don't forget that you must have a means of verifying the integrity of the code.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not finding it on Github.  Is it hosted elsewhere?

Nevermind, seems to be self-hosted: https://gitweb.torproject.org/builders/tor-browser-bundle.git/tree/gitian/README.build